# Change order of list of lists according to another list

Tags: python

I have a bunch of CSV-files where first line is the column name, and now I want to change the order according to another list.
Example:

```
[
['date','index','name','position'],
['2003-02-04','23445','Steiner, James','98886'],
['2003-02-04','23446','Holm, Derek','2233'],
...
]
```

The above order differs slightly between the files, but the same column-names are always available.

So the I want the columns to be re-arranged as:

```
['index','date','name','position']
```

I can solve it by comparing the first row, making an index for each column, then re-map each row into a new list of lists using a for-loop.
And while it works, it feels so ugly even my blind old aunt would yell at me if she saw it.

Someone on IRC told me to look at on `map()` and `operator` but I'm just not experienced enough to puzzle those together. :/

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a job for `csvreader` [https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Plain Python

You could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose your data:

```
data = [
['date','index','name','position'],
['2003-02-04','23445','Steiner, James','98886'],
['2003-02-04','23446','Holm, Derek','2233']
]

columns = list(zip(*data))
print(columns)
# [('date', '2003-02-04', '2003-02-04'), ('index', '23445', '23446'), ('name', 'Steiner, James', 'Holm, Derek'), ('position', '98886', '2233')]
```

It becomes much easier to modify the columns order now.

To calculate the needed permutation, you can use:

```
old = data[0]
new = ['index','date','name','position']
mapping = {i:new.index(v) for i,v in enumerate(old)}
# {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

You can apply the permutation to the columns:

```
columns = [columns[mapping[i]] for i in range(len(columns))]
# [('index', '23445', '23446'), ('date', '2003-02-04', '2003-02-04'), ('name', 'Steiner, James', 'Holm, Derek'), ('position', '98886', '2233')]
```

and transpose them back:

```
list(zip(*columns))
# [('index', 'date', 'name', 'position'), ('23445', '2003-02-04', 'Steiner, James', '98886'), ('23446', '2003-02-04', 'Holm, Derek', '2233')]
```

## With Pandas

For this kind of tasks, you should use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).
It can parse CSVs, reorder columns, sort them and keep an index.

If you have already imported `data`, you could use these methods to import the columns, use the first row as header and set `index` column as index.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]).set_index('index')
```

`df` then becomes:

```
            date            name position
index
23445  2003-02-04  Steiner, James    98886
23446  2003-02-04     Holm, Derek     2233
```

You can avoid those steps by importing the CSV correctly with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). You'd need `usecols=['index','date','name','position']` to get the correct order directly.

Comment: Or with Pandas you could handle the header in the constructor, i.e. `pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]).set_index('index')`

Answer (score 2):

Simple and stupid:

```
LIST = [
    ['date', 'index', 'name', 'position'],
    ['2003-02-04', '23445', 'Steiner, James', '98886'],
    ['2003-02-04', '23446', 'Holm, Derek', '2233'],
]

NEW_HEADER = ['index', 'date', 'name', 'position']


def swap(lists, new_header):

    mapping = {}

    for lst in lists:
        if not mapping:
            mapping = {
                old_pos: new_pos
                for new_pos, new_field in enumerate(new_header)
                for old_pos, old_field in enumerate(lst)
                if new_field == old_field}

        yield [item for _, item in sorted(
            [(mapping[index], item) for index, item in enumerate(lst)])]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(LIST)
    print(list(swap(LIST, NEW_HEADER)))
```

Comment: You seem to like constructive criticism, so here goes: This code isn't simple  (but it's not stupid either ;) ). You could create `mapping` in a single dict comprehension (see my answer). You could also create `new_order` with a list comprehension. Anyway, your solution seems to work fine, so you get my vote.

Comment: Updated my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

To rearrange your data, you can use a dictionary:

```
import csv
s = [
['date','index','name','position'],
['2003-02-04','23445','Steiner, James','98886'],
['2003-02-04','23446','Holm, Derek','2233'],

]
new_data = [{a:b for a, b in zip(s[0], i)} for i in s[1:]]
final_data = [[b[c] for c in ['index','date','name','position']] for b in new_data]
write = csv.writer(open('filename.csv'))
write.writerows(final_data)
```

Comment: If you use `a` as `s[0]` as a key, you will lose data, since `s[0]` is not unique.